# How to use python shift function to increase the values of a cell by using the previous row value of that particular column?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column 'Y' which has boolean values. I want to create a new column X which depends on the value of Y and X itself. So if Y is False i want X's value to be 1 and if Y is True i want X's value to be X's previous rows value +1. I need the following output:

```
Y     X
False 1
True  2
True  3
False 1
False 1
True  2
True  3
```

I am trying shift function df.loc[df['Y']==True,'X'] = df.X.shift(1)+1
but not getting the desired output. I am getting the output as

```
    Y   X
0   False   1.0
1   True    2.0
2   True    2.0
3   False   1.0
4   False   1.0
5   True    2.0
6   True    2.0
```

The second time Y is having a True value it should increment X by 1 using the previous value of X.

i do not prefer loops/iteration since i have 5 million rows of data and iteration would take hours of processing time.

```
df.loc[df['Y']==True,'X'] = df.X.shift(1)+1

columns = ['Y']
index =0,1,2,3,4,5,6
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
df['Y'] = True
df.loc[0,'Y']= False
df.loc[3,'Y']= False
df.loc[4,'Y']= False

df.loc[:,'X']=1
df.loc[df['Y']==True,'X'] = df.X.shift(1)+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid shift cannot handle this case, at least I tried many times.

Here provide another way to deal with it.

```
## your codes about initializing df

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ['Y']
index = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
df['Y'] = True
df.loc[0, 'Y'] = False
df.loc[3, 'Y'] = False
df.loc[4, 'Y'] = False

df.loc[:, 'X'] = 1

print(df)

### initializing of df ends here

### my codes start here


# create an assist column holding the cumsum of X column
df['cum'] = df.X.cumsum()

# calculate the offset
df['offset'] = df.apply(lambda s: 0 - s.cum if s.Y is False else np.nan, axis=1).fillna(method='ffill') + 1

# modify the X column by cumsum and calculated offset
df['X'] = df['cum'] + df['offset']

df.X = df.X.astype(int)
# remove assist columns leaving only the Y, X column
df = df[['Y', 'X']]

print(df)
```

The result looks like this, and I think it's what you badly wanted, and due to it uses pandas to calculate, it won't be that slow like for-loop in pure python codes:

```
       Y  X
0  False  1
1   True  1
2   True  1
3  False  1
4  False  1
5   True  1
6   True  1

       Y  X
0  False  1
1   True  2
2   True  3
3  False  1
4  False  1
5   True  2
6   True  3
```

You can check more details about what the dataframe looks like by adding **print(df)** before these two columns (cum, offset) were removed.

Calculating the cum, offset column:

```
       Y  X  cum  offset
0  False  1    1     0.0
1   True  1    2     0.0
2   True  1    3     0.0
3  False  1    4    -3.0
4  False  1    5    -4.0
5   True  1    6    -4.0
6   True  1    7    -4.0
```

Updating the X column:

```
       Y    X  cum  offset
0  False  1.0    1     0.0
1   True  2.0    2     0.0
2   True  3.0    3     0.0
3  False  1.0    4    -3.0
4  False  1.0    5    -4.0
5   True  2.0    6    -4.0
6   True  3.0    7    -4.0
```

Comment: Thanks. I had one more similar problem.

Comment: @shreeja7, what is your problem?

Comment: I have 2 columns(FN1 and FN2) and i have to create one more column(Final)                                                  
FN1     FN2    Final
False   False   1
True    True    1
False   False   1
True    False   2
True    True    2
False   False   1 
True    True    1
True    True    1.                                                                                                              If FN1 is False, Final will be 1. If FN2 is True i will be the previous value of Final. But if FN2 is False i need to update it with the previous value of Final +1 (i.e. increment by 1).

Comment: Yes i have voted for the answer but it wont be shown publicly since I just joined and have less points. However, my vote has been recorded

Comment: The other problem seems a little bit harder than this one, hmmmm

Comment: You'd better ask another question, and I'll try to think about it. Otherwise I don't even have a place to answer it with good code format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744194/how-to-use-python-apply-lambda-shift-function-to-get-the-previous-row-value-of-t

Comment: could you help me out with the second problem?