# How to use python apply/lambda/shift function to get the previous row value of that particular column based on the value of 2 columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns(FN1 and FN2) and based on these i have to create one more column(Final)

```
FN1     FN2    Final
False   False   1
True    True    1
False   False   1
True    False   2
True    True    2
False   False   1 
True    True    1
True    True    1
```

- If FN1 is False, Final will be 1.
- If FN2 is True i will be the previous value of Final.
- But if FN2 is False i need to update it with the previous value of
  Final +1 (i.e. increment by 1)

. I tried doing it using `shift()` but again that does not help in this scenario.

```
FN1     FN2    Final
False   False   1
True    True    1
False   False   1
True    False   2
True    True    2
False   False   1 
True    True    1
True    True    1
```

.

Comment: FYI your input dataframe and output are same after applying the logic.

Comment: My input df has 2 columns FN1 and FN2. My output df should have one more column "Final" based on the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.select`:

```
df1 = df.shift()

cond1 = df['FN1'] == False
cond2 = (df['FN1']==True) & (df['FN2'] ==True)
cond3 = (df['FN1']==True) & (df['FN2'] == False)

df['Final'] = np.select([cond1,cond2,cond3], [1, df1['Final'], df1['Final']+1])

print(df)
```

Comment: This does not work as expected.  The first time it encounters  cond3 it increments the value by 1. But just after that it encounters cond2 it stores the value as 1 instead of 2 (which is now the prev row's value). It is giving the following output FN1     FN2    Final
False   False   1
True    True    1
False   False   1
True    False   2
True    True    1
False   False   1 
True    True    1
True    True    1

Answer (score 1):

using a lambda:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'FN1': [False, True, False, True, True, False, True, True],
                   'FN2': [False, True, False, False, True, False, True, True]
                   })

def f(fn1, fn2):
    global previousfinal
    previousfinal = 1 if not fn1 else previousfinal + 1 if not fn2 else previousfinal
    return previousfinal

previousfinal = 1
df['Final'] = df[['FN1', 'FN2']].apply(lambda x: f(*x), axis=1)
print(df)
```